# How can I use regex to split a string by {}

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var string = '{user: Jack}{user: Dave}{user: John}{user: Hou}';
```

How can I use regex to split this string and save the result in an array like

```
['{user: Jack}','{user: Dave}','{user: John}','{user: Hou}'] ?
```

Comment: Why don't you use JSON instead?

Comment: will there by nested {} inside a {}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use that expression as param of the [String.prototype.match() method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp).

```
\{(.*?)\}
```

This will make a thing like that:

```
var str = '{user: Jack}{user: Dave}{user: John}{user: Hou}';
var res = str.match(/\{(.*?)\}/g);
```

It will give you an array like you want it.
If you have to use regex a lot, you can use this cool regex tester: https://regex101.com/

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Or simply using look ahead:

```
var arr = string.split(/(?=\{)/);
```

```js
var string = '{user: Jack}{user: Dave}{user: John}{user: Hou}';

document.write(string.split(/(?=\{)/));
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a test for some string (not JSON), use the following regexp:

```
var string = '{user: Jack}{user: Dave}{user: John}{user: Hou}',
    re = /\{\w+?:\s?\w+?\}/g;

console.log(string.match(re));
// ["{user: Jack}", "{user: Dave}", "{user: John}", "{user: Hou}"]
```

Comment: is there a reason you make the \w matches non-greedy? Because it works without equally.

Comment: @AntonHarald, this is called optimization of regular expressions(if you don't know).

Comment: I think here doesn't make a difference. I couldn't see a performance plus in a test. but maybe you want to convince me of the opposite..

Comment: @AntonHarald, "I couldn't see a performance plus" - you can tell me about performance plus or minuses after you have presented the measurement results with ungreedy operators and without them. You don't see the difference? What if the string would be a much longer?

Comment: hey, I was just curious. this wasn't meant to sound offensive... Maybe not the most professional testing result report. But, how would I do it better? At the moment, I timed this in node.js: time - long-for-loop - time. With this I never get better results using the non-greedy operators. it looks to me that the longer the strings get, the better perform the greedy ones.

Comment: it depends on regex pattern complexity. Also time is not the only factor, there is also differrence in memory consumption

Answer (score 1):

If there is no nested `{}` inside `{}`, then try

```js
var string = '{user: Jack}{user: Dave}{user: John}{user: Hou}';

var output = string.split("}{").map(function(val, index, arr) {
  if (index == 0 ) 
  {
    if ( arr.length > 0 )
    {
      val += "}";
    }
  } 
  else if (index == arr.length - 1) 
  {
    val = "{" + val;
  } 
  else 
  {
    val = "{" + val + "}";
  }
  return val;
});

document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(output, 0, 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

Split on this `regex`

```
(?=(?!^){)
```

*JS Code*

```js
var string = '{user: Jack}{user: Dave}{user: John}{user: Hou}';

document.write(string.split(/(?=(?!^){)/));
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/QnBvoQ)**

Comment: trying to understand your negative look-ahead inside the positive one. Could you provide an example, where this is necessary?

Comment: @AntonHarald Not necessary, but I wanted to make sure that it does not split if `{` is in starting

Comment: @AntonHarald check:- https://regex101.com/r/yN7aY4/1

If negative lookahead is not used then the split will be also done from starting(might be)..give a try without negative lookaheads

Comment: alright, I see. well, "a".split("^"); // ["a"], so i think splitting at the beginning is not so bad, anyways. I get the point. thx.

Comment: @AntonHarald i wasn't trying to complicate it..I assumed that if split will be done if I don't use negative lookahead, then it will be split anything before first `{` which is nothing